# 502 Bad Gateway with Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, grails

I have a web application running on an ubuntu server.

I use HAProxy as a proxy that points to my webserver, which is Tomcat 7. My application runs on a servlet. My Servlet is build from a Grails application. I also use the [Resource](http://grails.org/plugin/resources) plugin for Grails, which should handle the resoures correctly. Everthing works fine but sometimes I see this error in the browser:

[image]

In my Servlet I set:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Here a a few example where I have get this erros from Chrome developer tools:

Example 1: 
[image]

Example 2: 
[image]
It helps a little but anyway sometimes I see the error. What do I have to do to fix this error?

Example 3:
[image]

Comment: try using absolute path instead of relative path.

Comment: @ankit I updated my question with a few example. I am not sure why the resource framework does not handle this correctly do you have an idea?

Comment: Make a request to one of the URLs above directly to Tomcat (bypassing HAProxy) and post the response (headers).

Comment: @Jukka how do I bypass HAProxy?

Comment: Make a request directly to Tomcat's ip:port with e.g. wget or curl or RESTclient (for firefox)

Comment: @Jukka this does not help.

Comment: Did you make the request and get the response headers like I suggested?